# Having error using dynamic query OrderFactoryUtil

Tags: java, liferay

I'm trying to create a dynamic query with OrderFactoryUtil to sort my query. Here's my code:

```
        public List<BirFormNumbers> getAllBirFormNumbers() throws SystemException{
           DynamicQuery BirFormNumbersdynamicQuery = DynamicQueryFactoryUtil.forClass(BirFormNumbersImpl.class);
           Order order = OrderFactoryUtil.asc("bfnsCode");
           BirFormNumbersdynamicQuery.addOrder(order);
        return BirFormNumbersLocalServiceUtil.dynamicQuery(BirFormNumbersdynamicQuery);
    }
```

Then I got this error

```
{"message":"org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: bfnsCode of: com.pmti.bir.mrcos.model.impl.BirFormNumbersImpl","exception":"com.liferay.portal.kernel.exception.SystemException"}   

03:07:35,530 ERROR [http-bio-8080-exec-4][BasePersistenceImpl:244] Caught unexpected exception org.hibernate.QueryException
```

I have seen other example using this code and it's working for them. I'm wondering where did I got the error or what happened in there. Thanks

**EDIT:**

```
    <!-- PK FIELDS -->
    <column name="taxtId" type="long" primary="true" id-type="identity"
        db-name="TAXT_ID" />
    <column name="bfnsCode" type="String" db-name="BFNS_CODE" />

    <!-- PK FIELDS -->
    <column name="taxtCode" type="String" primary="true" db-name="TAXT_CODE" />
    <!-- FIELDS -->
    <column name="taxtDesc" type="String" db-name="TAXT_DESC" />
    <column name="acctCode" type="String" db-name="ACCT_CODE" />
    <column name="createdDate" type="Date" db-name="CREATED_DATE" />
    <column name="createdBy" type="String" db-name="CREATED_BY" />
    <column name="lastModifiedDate" type="Date" db-name="LAST_MODIFIED_DATE" />
    <column name="lastModifiedBy" type="String" db-name="LAST_MODIFIED_BY" />
    <column name="taxtStatus" type="String" db-name="TAXT_STATUS" />

    <finder return-type="Collection" name="_bfnsCode">
        <finder-column name="bfnsCode"></finder-column>
    </finder>
</entity>
```

Here's the declaration in my service.xml

Comment: Could you post a declaration of `BirFormNumbers` here?

Comment: What part? model is auto generated right?

Comment: Is the field name appropriately named in DB as per query?

Comment: @chiradee I assume entity declaration from `service.xml`. I just want to make sure that `bfnsCode` is declared properly.

Comment: Yes I declared it as string in service.xml and the datatype of bfnsCode in DB is varchar. This also happens in some of my models. I can't use the OrderFactoryUtil because it gives me the same error.

Comment: @defaultlocale I already put my service.xml. Please see edit.

Comment: @chiradee I'm not sure if it helps, but are you sure that you need an `Impl` class in dynamic query initialization? Shouldn't it be: `DynamicQueryFactoryUtil.forClass(BirFormNumbers.class);`?